# How to use MySQL functions in CakePHP save() function

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've MySQL Query like this

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname, amount) VALUES ('Suresh', ABS('-400'));
```

It inserts data like this

```
Suresh | 400
```

Same Query with CakePHP Model

```
$this->User->query("INSERT INTO users (firstname, amount) VALUES ('Suresh', ABS('-400'))");
```

It inserts data like this

```
Suresh | 400
```

Now My Question is How Can I use MySQL functions with CakePHP save() function

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     $this->User->create();
     $this->request->data['User']['firstname'] = "Suresh";    //This is inserting in database
     $this->request->data['User']['amount'] = "ABS('-400')";  //This is not inserting in database
     $this->User->save($this->request->data);
}
```

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Firstname is inserting ?

Comment: Yeah I've tried with `ABS(-400)` I can use PHP function, but I want to use MySQL functions @sagi

Comment: Yes Firstname is inserting @AlimonKarim

Comment: `"ABS(400)"` won't perform on the MySQL side? for PHP function shouldn't it be ABS(-400) without the quotes? I think there is a problem with using ABS function on string values.

Comment: There is no issue with quotes, I have tried with both `ABS(-400)` or `ABS('-400')`  but still I can't get that value in table @sagi

Comment: You should have choosen a different example. `ABS()` can be easily solved at PHP level, there is absolutely no need to handle this at SQL level.

Comment: I know this can be handled by PHP side also, but I'm curious to know how can i use MySQL function with save() function, It allows in query() function but not allowing in save() function. @ndm

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use a DboSource expression, for example:

```
$this->request->data['User']['amount'] =
    $this->User->getDataSource()->expression('ABS(-400)');
```

Expression objects are not going to be sanitized or escaped, but inserted into the query as is.

A word of warning, be careful what you are passing, in case the `-400` would actually be user input, you would need to make sure that it is being sanitized/casted/validated properly!

See also

- **[API > DboSource::expression()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-DboSource.html#_expression)**

Comment: After applying your code i got this error
"Non-static method DboSource::expression() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context.."

Is there anything I'm missing? or I've to include anything?

Comment: @ShriSuresh Just like the error message says, [**the method**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-DboSource.html#_expression) isn't static, so it shouldn't be called that way. Use `$this->User->getDataSource()->expression()` instead. And a word of warning, be careful what you are passing, in case the `-400` would actually be user input, you would need to make sure that it is being sanitized/casted properly!

Comment: I used `$connection->newQuery()->newExpr('WorkoutOrder + 1')` successfully to increment a column, note the warning from ndm though

Answer (score 0):

Change your code

```
$this->request->data['User']['amount'] = "ABS('-400')";  // here you are sending string.
```

To

```
$this->request->data['Album']['amount'] = ABS('-400');
```

Comment: I would Like to use MySQL functions not PHP function, in above case it's using PHP function.